# how to add data to http response

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, visual-studio

I have written a program in Visual Studio that can send an HttpWebRequest that will update the server.  On the server I have written an aspx file with Visual Studio Express for Web that can take the data and update an SQL Server database and then show the table on a page with a GridView.

What I want to do is put data into the aspx files response back to the program.  It would be the entire data base table of FName LName and UserNumber.  Response.Write("stuff"); puts "stuff" at the beginning of response.  What is the best way to add the data to the response not for the purpose of viewing on the web but to store in a local database by the VS program?  Thank you tw

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Anways I guess you can try wrapping the resultset(csv) into a hidden textfield/area and pass it back with aspx page; you can extract & store it in db. 

Otherwise you can go for json/xml for response, which you can easily read and store in db.

Comment: Thank you.I am looking into json.net.Haven't used that before but I am getting knowledge.